# Dreamweaver: Auto-correct

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

In Notepad++ when you type a wrong tag or a wrong word, the color will stay black instead of blue. How do you set up this preference in Dreamweaver CC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver has the ***Highlight Invalid HTML*** option, which will highlight invalid tags or markup in yellow.  To enable this option, click on **Code View Options** under the **View** menu and select **Highlight Invalid HTML**.

You can enable this option via the keyboard by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>H</kbd>.